# Date Stamp for Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

Need some help with this script. Only one of the desired date stamps is working. Right now data entry in column 19 prompts a date stamp in column 20, however nothing happens in column 14 when data is entered in column 13.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    var colToWatch = 13 
    var colToStamp = 14
    var colToWatch = 19 
    var colToStamp = 20

    if (sh.getName() !== 'Pending Orders'
        || e.range.columnStart != colToWatch
        || e.range.rowStart < 4)  {
            return;
    }

    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
        .setValue(new Date())
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code is overwriting the previously assigned values (there two lines `var colToWatch` and two `var colToStamp`)

You should use different variables names on each `var` code lines and to change `if` condition accordingly.

Related

- [Google sheets timestamp different cell ranges on a row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37266021/1595451)
- [Auto-timestamp multiple columns in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44849147/1595451)